# Perturbations of Neumann $\bar \partial$-Laplacian

Tags: several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a smooth, bounded, strongly pseudoconvex domain. Let $\square =\bar \partial \bar \partial^*+\bar \partial^* \bar \partial $ and suppose that $X$ is a first order differential operator. I am interested in mapping properties of the perturbated operator $$\square + X$$ under natural $\bar \partial$-Neumann boundary conditions.

To be more concrete, let $\mathcal{H}_0$ be the space of $L^2$-integrable $(0,1)$-forms on $\Omega$ and consider the unbounded, self-adjoint operator  $$\mathcal{L}:\mathcal{H}_0\supset \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{L})\rightarrow\mathcal{H}_0$$
from *[Taylor, PDE II, Chapter 12.3]*. Recall that $\mathcal{L}$ can e.g., be obtained as closure of $\square$, intially defined on the domain $\mathcal{D}^{0,1}=\{u\in C^\infty(\bar \Omega,\Lambda^{0,1}): \sigma u\vert_{\partial M}=0\}$, where $\sigma$ is defined in terms of the symbol of $\bar \partial^*$ and encodes the $0$th order $\bar \partial$-Neumann condition.

In Taylor's book we learn that $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{L})\subset H^1(\Omega,\Lambda^{0,1})\cap H^2_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega,\Lambda^{0,1})$ and so if $X$ is a first order differential operator (sending $(0,1)$-forms to $(0,1)$-forms), then $\mathcal{L}+X:\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{L})\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$ is a well defined closed operator.

**Question.** In the setting just described, is $\mathcal{L}+X$ Fredholm?

We already know that $\mathcal{L}$ is Fredholm (+ injective, hence invertible) and so it would suffice to show that $X:\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{L})\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$ is compact. If we knew that $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{L})$ would lie in $H^{1+\epsilon}(\Omega,\Lambda^{0,1})$ for some $\epsilon >0$, this would be clear. However, this would require improved subelliptic estimates for $\mathcal{L}$. From what I can tell reading Taylor's book there are such improved versions on *anisotropic* Sobolev spaces, but I doubt that this will lead to desired result unless the first order part of $X$ is adapted to the anisotropy.